# how to vertical align text before blockarray in blkarray package?

Tags: vertical-alignment, matrices, bordermatrix

I have to label row and column index around matrix. I know `blkarray` would help, so I write like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blkarray}% http://ctan.org/pkg/blkarray
\newcommand{\matindex}[1]{\mbox{#1}}% Matrix index

\begin{document}

pmatrix way:
\[
J(i,j,\theta)=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & c & \cdots & -s & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & s & \cdots & c & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
\]

blkarray way:
\[
  J(i,j,\theta)=\begin{blockarray}{cccccccc}
    \begin{block}{(ccccccc)c}
        1 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
        \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots \\
        0 & \cdots & c & \cdots & -s & \cdots & 0 & \matindex{$i$} \\
        \vdots & & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
        0 & \cdots & s & \cdots & c & \cdots & 0 & \matindex{$j$} \\
        \vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        0 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 1 \\
    \end{block}
    & & \matindex{$i$} & & \matindex{$j$} & \\
  \end{blockarray}
\]

Why $J(i,j,\theta)$ isn't vertical aligned int blkarray way?
\end{document}
```

Here is the result:
[image]
I want to know why [image] isn't vertical aligned in blkarray way.

And how to vertical aligned it like pmatrix way.

Thanks.

Comment: It *is* vertically aligned, but takes into aaccount the supplementary row with $i$ and $j$.

Comment: @Bernard: If you remove the extra row it isn't aligned either, and if you add \\[-2cm] at the end the J(i,...) doesn't move.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: I know `blkarray` has some problems with vertical centring, and I should have tested to see what happens really. Anyway, I have a solution with `\raisebox` and another with `pst-node`. Please see my post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the block array is vertically centered with respect to its entire size, including the indices below.

The easiest way, in this case, is to put the whole thing in the `blkarray`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blkarray}% http://ctan.org/pkg/blkarray

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{blockarray}{r@{}cccccccc}
\begin{block}{r(ccccccc)c}
                 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
                 & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots \\
                 & 0 & \cdots & c & \cdots & -s & \cdots & 0 & i \\
J(i,j,\theta)={} & \vdots & & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
                 & 0 & \cdots & s & \cdots & c & \cdots & 0 & j \\
                 & \vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
                 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 1 \\
\end{block}
                 & & & i & & j & \\
\end{blockarray}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: wow, your solution is really elegant, thanks.

Comment: I just found a problem too, what if the number of rows is even? which row should `J(i,j,\theta)={}` be placed to ?

Comment: @egreg: See what happens if you have to add some maths after the blockarray, say `\times A`.

Comment: @Bernard Of course: I said “in this particular case”.

Answer (score 6):

You can obtain this result either with `pmatrix`and `pstricks`, defining certain elements as nodes, and attaching labels to these nodes, or with `blockarray, stackengine` or `makecell`, and a `\raisebox` command:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{blkarray, makecell,  stackengine}
\usepackage{pst-node, auto-pst-pdf} %

\begin{document}

\verb|pmatrix way + pstricks way:|\bigskip

\[
 \begin{postscript}
 J(i,j,\theta)=%
 \begin{pmatrix}
1 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots\\
0 & \cdots & c & \cdots & -s & \cdots &\rnode{rowi}{0}\\%
\vdots & & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & s & \cdots & c & \cdots & \rnode{rowj}{0}\\%
\vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & \rnode{coli}{0} & \cdots & \rnode{colj}{0} & \cdots & 1
\end{pmatrix}
 \psset{labelsep=1.2em}
\nput{0}{rowi}{i}\nput{0}{rowj}{j}
 \psset{labelsep=1.2ex}
\nput{-90}{coli}{i}\nput{-90}{colj}{j}
\end{postscript}
\]

\verb|blkarray + makecell or stackengine way:  |
\[
  J(i,j,\theta)= \raisebox{-0.3\baselineskip}{$ \begin{blockarray}{(*{7}{c})c}
        1 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
        \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots \\
        0 & \cdots & c & \cdots & -s & \cdots & 0 & i\\ 
        \vdots & & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
        0 & \cdots & s & \cdots & c & \cdots & 0 & j \\
        \vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        0 & \cdots & \smash{\stackunder[1.2ex]{0}{$ i $}} & \cdots &\smash{\makecell[tc]{0\\j}} & \cdots & 1
  \end{blockarray} $} 
\]%

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well thanks, It really works, but I have to adjust the `-0.8` in other cases, It's not that elegant. Hope bug fixed.

Comment: Yes, this value was found by trial and errors. Maybe someone knows the length that's involved in vertical spacing of rows?

Comment: @user1024: I've modified the code for the solution with `blkarray`. It simplifies the code (no  more `block`).

Answer (score 2):

With `{pNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`, you will have directly the expected result.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
J(i,j,\theta)=\begin{pNiceMatrix}[last-row=8,last-col=8]
1 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & c & \cdots & -s & \cdots & 0 & i \\
\vdots & & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & s & \cdots & c & \cdots & 0 & j \\
\vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 1 \\
  & & i & & j & \\
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]